# Excel: How to use a checkbox form marco to hide column on MAC

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I'm using an activeX checkbox with the following Macro in my worksheet:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If CheckBox1 = True Then
   Columns("P:V").Hidden = True
Else
   Columns("P:V").Hidden = False
End If
End Sub
```

And it works fine on my PC.  But when I try to do it on Mac, it doesn't work since Mac doesn't have activeX support.  I tried using a regular form control checkbox, but it doesn't appear to function at all when I use this macro.  Anyone have any ideas?  I'm kind of a VBA/Excel noob.

Comment: Forms controls function differently from ActiveX - you will need to assign a macro directly to the Forms checkbox (right-click -> Assign macro). You can reference the checkbox in the macro using something like `ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ControlFormat.Value`

Comment: So is it possible to make a macro that is MAC friendly that uses a form checkbox to hide a column?

Comment: I don't see why not, if you use Forms controls. But I don't have access to a Mac, so I can't say 100%.

Comment: I'm an excel noob so, when I create a new form checkbox.  I right click it, and put in "assign macro." I created a new one, and put in the code above and used the CheckBox3  but it doesn't work. I'm not sure what you were saying when I need to reference it with that code.

Comment: See my example below.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it. When I try to run this code, it gives a compiler error.  It doesn't appear to like the ".Shapes"

Comment: Sorry - that works for me on Windows, but I'm not familiar with Excel on Mac at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put two Forms checkboxes on a sheet and name them "cbB" and "cbC" you can assign the macro below to both of them.  Which column is affected will depend on which checkbox triggers the Sub.

Code is for a regular module: if you want it in the sheet module then I would replace `ActiveSheet` with `Me`

```
Sub CheckBox_Click()

    Dim vis As Boolean, ac As String, col As String

    ac = Application.Caller

    With ActiveSheet

        vis = (.Shapes(ac).ControlFormat.Value = 1)

        Select Case ac
            Case "cbB": col = "B"
            Case "cbC": col = "C"
        End Select

        If col <> "" Then .Columns(col).Hidden = vis

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: When I used activesheet it worked! It's the "Me" it didn't like. Thank you again!